# conversion from 'double' to 'float' requires a narrowing conversion

Tags: c++, vector, floating-point

I have the following lines of code:

```
std::vector<float> qualities = { 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8 };
std::vector<float> percentages = { 0.15, 0.16, 0.17, 0.18 };
```

I get the error mentioned in the title for each element.
Why is that?

Comment: The code seems [fine](https://godbolt.org/z/z74xdo). What compiler version and flags are you using?

Comment: A concern, in general, includes double rounding.  Decimal text to `double` to `float` may differ from decimal text to `float`.

Comment: @chux: Or more directly the fact that OP asks to initialize an element to `0.6`, but that is impossible because the `float` cannot represent the number that is the `double` value of `0.6`.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2015 - Visual C++ 14.0

Answer (score 6):

You get the message because a constant of the form (e.g.) `0.5` is a `double`, and assigning a `double` to a `float` is a narrowing conversion.

To fix this, append `f` to each of your constants, e.g. `0.5f`.

Comment: But OP is not doing CTAD or anything. This should not be necessary I think.

Comment: @cigien It's the assignment (or, rather, the initialisation) that the compiler doesn't like.

Comment: Hmm, I can't seem to get an error or warning with c++17, -Wall -Wextra on gcc or clang.

Comment: @cigien Fair enough, let's wait for the OP to respond to your question.

Comment: @cigien try with -Wconversion

Comment: @cigien MSVC also reports it (without any special command line flags).

Comment: Aah, interesting, thanks for the tip. Not used to msvc much myself :(

Answer (score 2):

> > conversion from 'double' to 'float' requires a narrowing conversion
>
> I get the error mentioned in the title for each element. Why is that?

Because you are constructing a vector of floats using double literals. Such conversion is narrowing.

That said, such conversions are allowed in this context and the example is well-formed and should compile. I suspect that you've used some compiler options to ask the compiler to not compile some well-formed programs.

You can write a float literal by appending `f` to a double literal.

Comment: Maybe mentioning that `0.15f` would be a float literal ? That way, OP has an easy way to silence the warning.

Comment: @Jeffrey Mentioned.